# Can't call "MapAnnotation" When Trying To Code Pin Locations

Tags: xcode, dictionary, mkmapview, android-mapview

I can't call the class "MapAnnotation" on XCode 4. I'm working on coding that will allow me to place pins in an MKMapView. I believe I've imported the right delegates. Here's what I've got:

MillersLocations.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MKAnnotation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface MillersLocations : NSObject <MKAnnotation> {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
    NSString *title;
    NSString *subtitle;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;

@end
```

MillersLocations.m

```
#import "MillersLocations.h"

@implementation MillersLocations
@synthesize coordinate, title, subtitle;


-(void)dealloc{
    [title dealloc];
    [subtitle dealloc];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

And here's my view controller for the map view:

MapViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface MapViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate> {
    IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;

}

@end
```

MapViewController.m (just the segment I'm looking at)

```
#import "MapViewController.h"
#import "MillersLocations.h"

@implementation MapViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}

//skipping forward

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    MKCoordinateRegion store1;
    store1.center.latitude = 36.8605679;
    store1.center.longitude = -76.2866713;
    store1.span.latitudeDelta = 0.1;
    store1.span.longitudeDelta = 0.1;
    [mapView setRegion:store1 animated:YES];    

    //this is where I'm trying to put this code in:
    MapAnnotation* annotation = [[MapAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:newCoord];
    //BUT "MapAnnotation" isn't an option
    }
```

I'm wondering if I haven't imported the rights classes or something. I've Googled it and can't seem to find where "MapAnnotation" lies. What do I need to import to get access to "MapAnnotation"? Everything works fine up until that point.

Thanks for the help. I'm just learning this stuff!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What makes you think that there is class called `MapAnnotation`?  Your annotation class is called `MillersLocations`.  You need to create instances of that class and call `[mapView addAnnotation:millersLocationInstance];` (or something similar).

Comment: Oh, duh...my bad. Thanks for the answer! My brain is still getting super scrambled. I appreciate the quick answer.